# Riemann to Influx timestamp

Tags: timestamp, precision, influxdb, seconds, riemann

I use an erlang-riemann client 'katja' to send events to riemann0.2.10 which in turn forwards it to influxdb0.9.5. When I send time in epoch upto the precision of a second(10 digits), it works fine. However, I need the timestamp to be more precise(milli/micro/nano seconds). When I forward more than 10 digits, riemann is unable to parse it. This could be an issue in the influx client for riemann(influx.clj line 176).
Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find out the fix.
We modify riemann.config to override influx.clj's 'event->point-9' function. The fix:
https://github.com/riemann/riemann/pull/601/commits/dcdf91f122f382bc24ed8f2b6b5709aa29774872

Riemann have presently chosen to not support nanoseconds, the above fix should work till then.